# Tagged along in a company acquisition but weird terms at new company. What should I do?

Tags: acquisition

I am a senior developer who recently went through an acquisition, but I have mixed feelings about the situation at the acquiring company.
In short, I am now at a big company on terms I didn't choose, being paid a startup salary without startup equity, and being stuck on teams I'm not super-interested in using a proprietary stack, in other to "prove myself" as permanently hirable. Is it worth it?

Comment: You should fin a new job.

Comment: This is a good cautionary tale.  If you take a startup salary, make sure you have "accelerated vestment" if the company is acquired.

Comment: Does "startup salary" have a different meaning in your location? Me and everyone I know who worked for a startup always had better salaries in them than in established big companies.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this situation actually all that bad, or just stinging my pride?
>   How bad is it to be treated this way as a senior developer?

It's typical of a startup having been acquired. I've been there and done that many times.

I always found that I enjoyed the startup culture, and almost always didn't enjoy the acquiring company's culture. I usually left the larger company.

Think of it this way - would you have applied for a job at the new company rather than the startup back when you had the choice? For me, the answer was always "No. Because that wasn't the kind of company I was looking for."

Try not to let pride get in the way of making the right move for your career. Worrying about the past or what could have been is like worrying about a sunk cost. Deal instead with what can be and what the future part of your career holds - that's the only part under your control.

> Is there anything I can do to improve my situation within Big Company?
>   Like talking to HR and my manager about placing me on a team faster?
>   Once I start doing grunt work to prove myself on some team, is there
>   any point in going to HR and trying to negotiate salary even though I
>   already accepted their offer and started?

Just work hard and try to find the best fit possible.

Every company is different. Keep your eyes open and talk to your colleagues (and perhaps your old boss) as you try to determine if it is possible/advisable to re-negotiate your salary.

> What would be the best way to try and negotiate without looking
>   ungrateful to my old boss (now manager) or making him look bad? He
>   already got me a bit more money and is getting me internal interviews,
>   the problem is just that I'm still far below market.

If you conclude that renegotiation is possible and advisable, you could just give your old boss a heads up. If you are on friendly terms, I suspect he will be happy for you and there won't be any issues for him.

> After the OP changed most of the question through an edit: Is it worth it?

Only you can decide if it's worth it to stick around or not. For me the answer was eventually always that it wasn't worth staying. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

You say you can renegotiate after 3 months if you are placed permanently. Why not stick it out (if you like the new company culture, etc) but look for new jobs at the same time. Either you find something better, and move on, or finish the 3 months and stay on. This seems like the best plan of action that doesn't involve fruitless speculation. Best of luck to you.